# Using Nested ViewControllers, is it possible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller, nested-views

I am trying to have a nested ViewControllers in my App, is that possible?

For example, I would have my View Controller with multiple Views inside it, but each view is so complicated and always updating and animating, that I want to make it an independent ViewController, is something of such possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible (and quite popular). Look for "container view controllers". [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html)

Comment: Does it allow the resizing of that Container?

Comment: Sure. In correct view controller hierarchy all layout related calls will be present. It was a problem before iOS 5 and child view controllers.
As I see, you ask many basic questions. Maybe you should read any good tutorial on iOS? I can recommend iOS video lectures from Stanford (free and publicly available) ;)

Comment: The documentation moved. now: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

Comment: Thanks @AndreasKraft, fixed link

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

Check out the Apple documentation for [UIViewControllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/addChildViewController:). It is possible to add child view controllers to your controller.

Comment: All I could find was viewControllers beside each other, I want to know if it is possible to make it as if it's a UIView on the ViewController, to be able to move around as well from the first viewController and be able to animate and function itself from within (second viewController that is)